# Subclass and use base class initialiser

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

I have this:

```
class foo {
public:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
```

Which is fine, but I want to add some operator overloading without modifying class foo:

```
class bar: public foo {
  operator==(const bar &x) const {
    return a == x.a;
  }
}
```

Fine so far, but now I need to initialise bar with an array of objects I get from another class. No problem, I can just copy all of the foo variables over to bar in a dedicated constructor:

```
bar::bar(foo &x) {
  a = foo.a;
  /* etc */
}
```

But this seems messy, and if class foo over gets updated, then I have to update bar too. Much preferable if bar could automatically initialise itself (it'll never contain its own data members)

Answer (score 2):

isn't it as simple as making sure Foo has a copy constructor.......

```
bar::bar(foo &x) 
: foo(x)
{
}

class foo {
foo::foo(foo &x)
{
  a = foo.a; /* etc */
}

};
```

Comment: `foo`, as given in the question, has a default copy constructor already. You don't have to add anything, just call it.

Comment: I've read it again and I don't see where it says Foo has a copy constructor already. 
I was under the impression he'd printed the entire relevant class definition for Foo in his example.

Comment: If the class looks like in the question, the compiler will generate a default copy constructor for it, doing a memberwise copy of all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, easy:

```
bar::bar(const foo& x)
  : foo(x)
{
}
```

Just use `foo`'s copy constructor. Everything between the `:` and the `{` is called the *initializer list*. You can directly initialize your members and base classes in there. For `foo`, the copy constructor could look like the following:

```
foo::foo(const foo& other)
  : a(other.a)
  , b(other.b)
  , c(other.c)
{
}
```

Note that I take both arguments by const reference, which is a good practice since you aren't touching the other objects. Also note that writing a copy constructor for `foo` yourself is not necessary most of the time, only when your class contains raw pointers (`int*` for example). The compiler will generate a copy ctor itself if you don't define one and just make a shallow copy of all data members.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting constructors can't be done in C++03, but can be approximated. Add these constructors:

```
template<class T1> bar(const T1& x1) : foo(x1) {}
template<class T1, class T2> bar(const T1& x1, const T2& x2) : foo(x1, x2) {}
template<class T1, class T2, class T3> bar(const T1& x1, const T2& x2, const T3& x3) : foo(x1, x2, x3) {}
// as much as you need...
```

In C++0x use a single variadic templated constructor and perfect forwarding.

Comment: *Huh*? If you just want the derived class to be initializable from the base class, that sure is possible in C++03.

Comment: @Xeo: copy initialized - possible. Inherit the constructors - impossible. Just try to extend `vector` with a new method and see what the problems are...

Comment: Anyway, apparently that's not exactly what the OP wanted... (although it solves his/her problem too).